# Error creating a page on the pages app on the magnolia admin central

Tags: magnolia

here is my template definition:

```
templateScript: /one-pager-module/templates/pages/main.ftl
renderType: freemarker
visible: true
title: One pager template
dialog: one-pager-module:pages/main
areas:
  content-sections:
    renderType: freemarker
availableComponents:
  content-items-list:
    id: one-pager-module:components/content-items-list
  textImage:
    id: one-pager-module:components/textImage
```

Here is my template script

```
[#assign title = content.title!"Eric's Classic Cars"]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="${content.keywords!""}"/>
    <meta name="description" content="${content.description!""}"/>
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>${title}</title>

    [#--bootstrap css--]
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/bootstrap-3.3.5/bootstrap.min.css ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/bootstrap-3.3.5/bootstrap-theme.min.css ">
    [#--Custom CSS--]
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/css/one-pager.css?z=123">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    [#--HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries--]
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    [@cms.page /]
</head>
<body>
  <h1>${title}</h1>
  <p>${content.subTitle!"No subtitle defined"}</p>

    [#--jquery and bootstrap js--]
    <script src="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/bootstrap-3.3.5/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/bootstrap-3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/bootstrap-3.3.5/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    [#--custom js--]
    <script src="${ctx.contextPath}/.resources/one-pager-module/webresources/js/one-pager.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my dialog definition

```
form:
  tabs:
    - name: tabText
      label: Title texts
      fields:
        - name: title
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          label: Title
        - name: subTitle
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          label: Subtitle
        - name: copyrightNote
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
          label: Copyright note
          description: Photographers who own the images used on this site

    - name: tabBgImage
      label: Background
      fields:
        - name: introBgImage
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
          targetWorkspace: dam
          appName: assets
          label: Select image
          description: Background image of the intro section
          identifierToPathConverter:
            class: info.magnolia.dam.app.assets.field.translator.AssetCompositeIdKeyTranslator
          contentPreviewDefinition:
            contentPreviewClass: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.DamFilePreviewComponent
    - name: tabMeta
      label: SEO
      fields:
        - name: keywords
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          i18n: true
          label: Keywords
          description: Keywords and description for search engine optimization
          rows: 3
        - name: description
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          i18n: true
          label: Description
          rows: 5
actions: !include /one-pager-module/dialogs/common/default-dialog-actions.yaml
```

when i create a page on the admin central i get this error.

```
info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException: Action execution failed for action: commit
....
Caused by: info.magnolia.config.registry.Registry$InvalidDefinitionException: one-pager-module:pages/main
```

What i am doing wrong? yet it had worked previously?
I am following the tutorial at: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Creating+a+page+template

Comment: I am able to create the page as long as i comment out the dialog on the page definition [ main.ftl ]

could it be a problem with the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be, but we'd need more information to know for sure.

In order for your template definition to be valid, everything it "pulls in" must also be valid, including your content-items-list component definition.  I have successfully added a page to the demo instance using your definitions above, of course without your content-items-list component, because it's not included here.

It could also be the case that your action includes are incorrect or in the wrong place.

Have you checked the 'Problems' tab in the Definitions app?

Comment: Hi, the problems tab does not give a lot of information. I am reading the calalina log.

Comment: I have re-installed magnolia again and now it is working. I do not know what the problem was before.